# Solspace Freeform Pro 4.0.12 Not Sending notify_user email

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm having some troubles with Freeform Pro.

I've got my forms working correctly, using the {exp:freeform:form} tag, the information is being logged into Freeform correctly, the Admins are getting the email, but the notify_user template doesn't seem to be working. I've read the documentation and it looks as if you have to use "notify_user", "user_email_field", and "user_notification_template" all together. I've got all three params in my Freeform tag, but cannot seem to figure out why they're not getting the email.

I'm using Ajax to send the forms and to run simple validation, but I don't think that would have any effect on the user emails, would it?

Here's my code:

```
    {exp:freeform:form form:class="jqtransform form_main" form_id="4" required="first_name|where_do_you_live|user_message" return="your-dreams-goals" admin_notify="my_email@address.com" notify_admin="yes" notify_user="yes" user_email_field="email" user_notification_template="default"}
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" />
    <input type="text" id="where_do_you_live" name="where_do_you_live" placeholder="Where do you live?" />
<textarea id="user_message" name="user_message" rows="5" cols="15" placeholder="Click here to type your dream or goal...">Click here to type your dream or goal...</textarea>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="purple">Would you like to send your dream or goal to yourself?</p>

<span>
<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
<label for="email" class="float-left">(Optional)</label>
</span>

<div class="clear"></div>

<span>
<input type="checkbox" id="accept" class="checkbox" />
<label for="accept" class="checkbox-label">By checking this box, you agree to share your Dreams and Goals on our website and other social media sites like Facebook and Twitter for others to see and enjoy.  We might also show them in our IPMG written materials.  We would only use your first name and city.  If you do not want us to show your Dreams and Goals, do not check this button, and they will be kept private.</label></span>

<input type="submit" class="cta float-left" id="form-main" onclick="return ValidateForm();" {/exp:freeform:form}
```

I have a notification template called "default" saved in Freeform.

Any ideas as to what may be going on? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try a really simple contact form, name, email with out anything else in the template so we can make sure FF is functioning properly with out any other scripts potentially effecting the behavior?

Comment: It turns out once I added all three parameters, changed the form type from Composer to Template, then set up the User Notification Template, it started working. I didn't realize I had to set up all those requirements; I thought the parameters I was passing in would override ALL of the Freeform Template tags.

This has been resolved!